# crawler is able to crawl only 30 results

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to crawl amazon website but crawler is working fine and giving result but it getting stops after 30 results crawled.I am getting by default 16 results from this website but if i change the settings.py (middleware )its showing 30 results.

---

```
import scrapy
class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "amazon"
allowed_domains = ["https://www.amazon.in"]
start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_4?url=search-
       alias%3Daps&fieldkeywords=lava+mobile+phones&sprefix
       =lava%2Caps%2C383&crid=1NBZO31560SIG&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Alava+
         mobile+phones'         
        ]
def parse1(self, response):
    q = '//div[contains(@class,"popover-
               grouping")]//a[contains(@class,"nav_a")]'
    global site
    for i in response.xpath(q):
        d1 = {
          'url' : site+' '.join(i.xpath('./@href').extract()),
          'Category': ' '.join(i.xpath('./text()').extract()),
          'MetaCategory': ' 
                   '.join(i.xpath('../../../h2/text()').extract())
        }
        url = d1['url']
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parseCategoryPage,meta=
                       {'src':d1})
def parseCategoryPage(self, response):
    src = response.meta['src']
    try:
        q = '//span[@class="a-list-item"]/a/span[text() = "See more"]/../@href'
        brand_url = site+response.xpath(q).extract()[1]
        src['brand_url'] = brand_url
        yield src]
    except Exception as e:
        # self.logger.debug('Exception occured:: %s',e)
        self.logger.exception(e)
        pass
def parse(self,response):
    q = '//li[contains(@id,"result_")]'
    for i in response.xpath(q):
        title = ''.join(i.xpath('.//h2/text()').extract())
        sp = ''.join(i.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"s-
                price")]/text()').extract())
        mp = ''.join(i.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"a-text-
                strike")]/text()').extract())
        purl = ''.join(i.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"s-
                price")]/../@href').extract())
        imgurl = ''.join(i.xpath('.//img[contains(@class,"s-access-
                 image")]/@src').extract())
        yield { "title" : title, "sp" : sp, "mrp" : mp, "pdp": purl, 
               "img":imgurl}
    paginate_next = 
        response.xpath('//span[@class="pagnLink"]/a/@href').extract()
    paginate_max = 
      response.xpath('//span[@class="pagnDisabled"]/text()').extract()
def parseBrandsPages(self,response):
    global site
    q = '//span[@class="pagnLink"]/a/@href'
    brands = response.xpath(q).extract()
    self.logger.debug('parsed the brands pages ')
    # self.logger.debug(brands)
    brand_pages = [ site+i for i in list(set(brands))]
    yield {"brand_pages" : brand_pages}
def parseBrands(self,response):
    global site
    q = '//span[@class="refinementLink"]'
    self.logger.debug('parsing the brands in the page')
    for i in response.xpath(q):
        url = site+''.join(i.xpath('../@href').extract())
        name = ''.join(i.xpath('./text()').extract())
        cnt = ''.join(i.xpath('./following-
           sibling::span/text()').extract())[2:-1]
        # print url,name,cnt
        yield { "url":url, "brand":name, "count":cnt}'
```

### Output

Only 30 results from amazon webpage from starting.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in 
retry_url
r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2017-08-01 11:22:02 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving 
   up
```

Comment: Please give a proper description of the error you see after 30 results!

Comment: @Klaus D.----------i have updated the error log.its showing in starting

Comment: If that happens after exactly 30 requests all the time, then you might be blocked by Amazon.

Comment: 30 items is crawling means there is a problem in settings .Amazon have not blocked me @Klaus D.